# Android picker intent returns URI of low quality image (thumbnail) Note 8

Tags: android, image, uri, picker, portrait

I am facing a strange issue and I hope someone can help me out.

I have a app which the user can select a picture from the gallery and them make some editions.... The problem happens on some devices, the returned URI of the picture loads a thumbnail of the picture.

On my Note 8 (with dynamic focus mode, AKA Portrait mode) it always returns the thumbnail of those pictures. I have no idea why.

My code:

```
private void openGallery(){

    Intent pickPhotoIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

    try{
        startActivityForResult(pickPhotoIntent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }catch (ActivityNotFoundException e){
        FirebaseCrash.report(e);

        if(mToast != null)
            mToast.cancel();

        mToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getResources().getText(R.string.no_gallery),Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        mToast.show();
    }
}


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if(requestCode == REQUEST_PRO){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            AnalyticsManager.UserEnteredIn(FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this),AnalyticsManager.PRICE);
            billingProcessor.purchase(Home.this,ImageXY.APESCT_PRO);
        }
    }
    else if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            if(data != null && data.getData() != null){
                onImageReceived(data.getData());
            }else
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Image Loading Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    if (!billingProcessor.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data))
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

public void onImageReceived(Uri imageUri) {

    Reference.image_uri = imageUri;

    Log.d("PICKER","RETURNED");
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ImageEditingActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Thanks in advance, I hope someone can help me.